# Getting template using ajax in Mustache Js

Tags: mustache, laravel-blade

For concatenating HTML tags and dynamic data, and insert the resulting UI markup into the DOM, I am using Mustache Js.

Below is the example code.

main.blade.php:

```
$.getJSON('json/data2.json', function(data) {
var template = $('#personTpl').html();
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
$('#sampleArea').html(html);
});
```

The template is defined as follows in index.html:

```
<script id="personTpl" type="text/template">
<h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
<p>Blog URL: <a href="{{blogURL}}">{{blogURL}}</a></p>
</script>
```

According to above code we are including the index.html(template) page in main.blade.php page. It is possible to access the index.html(template) page using ajax and append data from the current page.

And by this I can maintain the code easily and include the index.html(template) if i needed.

Comment: if you don't want to use such template-framework ,then you have to write function equivalent to  "Mustache.to_html(template,data)"  ,where you can map your "data" to corresponding fields in your "index.html" page.

Comment: No, I need to call the template not to include.